# Match item from JSON file to column values in a table

Tags: jquery, json

Is there a way to match values from JSON data to values in a column of a table?

```
var data =[
        { "code":"111","name":"one"},
        { "code":"222","name":"two"},
        { "code":"333","name":"three"},

        ];
$(this).find('td:nth-child(18)').each(function(i) {
                      if (($(this).text())  == data.code) {
                        //Not sure what to add here
                      }


                });
```

Outcome should be

```
ID  code  name
1    111  one
2    222  two
2    333  three
```

Where the `name` column would be generated according to the `code` column and JSON data

Comment: Not relevant, but I would still recommend underscore's [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) for this

Comment: Do you want to filter the json data, or do you want a list of the table cells?

Comment: Describe your expected outcome.

Comment: Please have look at the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be fairly easy if you used a data attribute on each row that contained the `code`

```
<tr data-code="111">
```

Then all you have to do is loop over your data and match rows using a selector

```
$.each(data, function(_, item){
    $('tr[data-code=' + item.code +'] td:last').text(item.name);
});
```

Or even simpler using `code` as row ID if all the codes are unique

`<tr id="111">`

```
$.each(data, function(_, item){
    $('#' + item.code + ' td:last').text(item.name);
});
```